# Map a list of one type to another in RxSwift but keep existing ones

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I've been running into this every now and then I'm always questioning myself whether I'm using RxSwift (or reactive means altogether) the wrong way.

The challenge is converting value types to something representable on the UI.

Usually on the lower level I'm storing data with simple types but I need something more stateful on the UI level. Just to give you an example, consider I have list of following types:

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
```

On the UI, however, I'm binding view models created from these items into a `UITableView` instance. I could achieve this by simply mapping from one type to another:

```
let displayedPersons = listOfPersons.map { PersonViewModel($0) }
```

This would make all items to be recreated on each update which I'm trying to avoid. I'm using MVVM and would like to keep the view model instances due to their transient state. Reloading table view on each update would also mess up animations.

I'm thinking if a custom binding could help here, binding one observable to another with cached mapping. Another solution that I've ended up doing is simply looping the observable so that when mapping, I get the previous value which I'll use as a cache.

Effectively I would need to map only the new items and keep the existing ones. Any ideas how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my very biased opinion, MVVM is good *only* for very complex UI where elements need to update dynamically and independently from each other. For all other cases I use my own library https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift (NB: it is not only for UI, but for UI as well). The core idea stems from MVI, and boils down to having a new snapshot of the state on every mutating event. So in your case the state would contain a collection of cached PersonViewModel, which will be partially updated upon receiving mutating events. The whole thing would be bound to UITableView via RxDataSources library.

Comment: Thanks, but I would disagree about MVVM being good only for (very) complex UI. I think it's a nice way of separating stateful UI along with its binding from the model or persistence layer. For me it's basically like a headless UI.

Comment: However, the question wasn't about MVVM itself. I'd be curious how would snapshotting work in cases where a change in bound value needs to be animated. For instance, if you have a favorite function in your app and that value is changed in the model? Also I feel in some scenarios there needs to be some kind of mediator postponing animation because of something on the UI.

Comment: for fields that require special treatment i am using *state.map().distinctUntilChanged()* as in *.select()* method here - https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift/blob/master/RaspSwift/RaspAggregator.swift ; but then again, if all or most of the fields are like that, MVVM will probably do better.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution that I'm currently using is simply to map and recycle the old items if they exist.

I've created an extension to make it work with sequences. In `memoryLookup` you will receive the previous values and can reuse any item from the previous round.

```
public extension ObservableType where E: Sequence {

    public func mapWithMemory<R>(memoryLookup: @escaping (Self.E.Element, [R]) throws -> R?, transform: @escaping (Self.E.Element) throws -> R) -> RxSwift.Observable<[R]> {
        return self.scan([]) { (acc, elements) -> [R] in
            let mapped = try elements.map { e in
                return try memoryLookup(e, acc) ?? transform(e)
            }
            return mapped
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an example usage where an array of `Int`s is mapped to array of `String`s.

```
func testMapWithMemory() {

    var creationCounts = [Int: Int]()

    let items = Observable.from([[1, 2],[2, 3],[2, 3]])

    let mapped = items.mapWithMemory(memoryLookup: { (item, previousItems) -> String? in
        return previousItems.first { $0 == "\(item)" }
    }) { (item) -> String in
        creationCounts[item, default: 0] += 1
        return "\(item)"
    }

    let xs = try! mapped.toBlocking().toArray().last!

    XCTAssertEqual(xs, ["2", "3"])
    XCTAssertEqual(creationCounts, [
        1: 1,
        2: 1,
        3: 1
        ])
}
```

Use at your own risk. And feel free to improve and share.

Also note that this is only useful if you need to avoid creating new items. In my case I'm using classes and binding UI elements to these items, so I don't want to recreate those.